# Unable to install email api extension

Tags: extension, civirules

I was just installing the email api and got the following error (Drupal 9.5.3 / CiviCRM 5.55.2 with email api 2.9)

Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the moment. You may want to contact your administrator or service provider with more details about what action you were performing when this occurred.
Could not find the SQL file.

The log gives me:

```
[error] 
$Fatal Error Details = array:3 [
  "message" => "Could not find the SQL file."
  "code" => null
  "exception" => CRM_Core_Exception {#5686
    -errorData: array:5 [
      "error_code" => 0
      "entity" => "Extension"
      "action" => "install"
      "is_error" => 1
      "error_message" => "Could not find the SQL file."
    ]
    #cause: null
    -_trace: null
    #message: "Could not find the SQL file."
    #code: 0
    #file: "/var/www/html/wct/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/api/api.php"
    #line: 135
    trace: {
      /var/www/html/wct/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/api/api.php:135 { …}
      /var/www/html/wct/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Admin/Form/Extensions.php:187 { …}
      /var/www/html/wct/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Core/Form.php:573 { …}
      /var/www/html/wct/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Core/StateMachine.php:144 { …}
      /var/www/html/wct/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Next.php:43 { …}
      /var/www/html/wct/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php:203 { …}
      /var/www/html/wct/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php:103 { …}
      /var/www/html/wct/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Core/Controller.php:355 { …}
      /var/www/html/wct/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Core/Page/Basic.php:334 { …}
      /var/www/html/wct/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Core/Page/Basic.php:140 { …}
      /var/www/html/wct/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Admin/Page/Extensions.php:105 { …}
      /var/www/html/wct/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:319 { …}
      /var/www/html/wct/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:69 { …}
      /var/www/html/wct/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:36 { …}
      /var/www/html/wct/web/modules/contrib/civicrm/src/Civicrm.php:88 {
        Drupal\civicrm\Civicrm->invoke($args)
        › ob_start();
        › $content = \CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke($args);
        › $output = ob_get_clean();
      }
      /var/www/html/wct/web/modules/contrib/civicrm/src/Controller/CivicrmController.php:80 { …}
      Drupal\civicrm\Controller\CivicrmController->main() {}
      /var/www/html/wct/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/EventSubscriber/EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber.php:123 { …}
      /var/www/html/wct/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Renderer.php:580 { …}
      /var/www/html/wct/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/EventSubscriber/EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber.php:124 { …}
      /var/www/html/wct/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/EventSubscriber/EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber.php:97 { …}
      /var/www/html/wct/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php:169 { …}
      /var/www/html/wct/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php:81 { …}
      /var/www/html/wct/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/Session.php:58 { …}
      /var/www/html/wct/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/KernelPreHandle.php:48 { …}
      /var/www/html/wct/web/core/modules/page_cache/src/StackMiddleware/PageCache.php:106 { …}
      /var/www/html/wct/web/core/modules/page_cache/src/StackMiddleware/PageCache.php:85 { …}
      /var/www/html/wct/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/ReverseProxyMiddleware.php:48 { …}
      /var/www/html/wct/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/NegotiationMiddleware.php:51 { …}
      /var/www/html/wct/vendor/stack/builder/src/Stack/StackedHttpKernel.php:23 { …}
      /var/www/html/wct/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/DrupalKernel.php:718 { …}
      /var/www/html/wct/web/index.php:19 { …}
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: can you check civicrm logs to find more details about the error?

Comment: Added the civicrm log message to the question (too long for a comment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sql file was missing from the extension folder (so the error message meant exactly what it said).